# Is it grammatical to say, "If it isn't X, then what is?"

Tags: meaning-in-context, contractions

I can't wrap my head about the difference between the two phrases below. A friend of mine, an U.K. national, told me that both are grammatical, but being not a linguist, she can't explain why.

A context is when someone is telling about having fun last holiday, concluding their speech with a phrase (1). To my understanding, only phrase (2) is correct, while (1) sounds like an awkward contraction.

> 1. If it is not a great holiday, then what is?
> 2. If it is not a great holiday, then what is it?

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but you'd say "a UK national" not "an UK national".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both sentences sound fine to me, but I'd read them with different emphasis and meaning:

1. If **it**'s not a great holiday, then what is *(a great holiday)*?
2. If it's not a great **holiday**, then what is it?

The first sentence is a rhetorical device.  The implication is that if you don't consider *it* a great holiday, then you probably shouldn't consider *anything* a great holiday--that's how good "it" is.  In context, this is the better sentence.  (Note that you'd never *say* the part I put in parentheses--I only added it to help explain.)

The second sentence is reacting in surprise.  The speaker thought it was a great holiday, but now they're learning it's something else.  They're asking what it is.  But this possibility is strange in context, so I might assume the question is *rhetorical*; if used this way, they're declaring it to be a great holiday by asking what else it could be.

Comment: +1 But in the first sentence *it's* would be unlikely - *it* just won't usually bear that much stress. We'd say *If **this** isn't* or *If **that** isn't*.

Comment: @StoneyB Ah, good point!  That does sound better.